# vmware.service hangs during shutdown

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, vmware

On Arch Linux, since a few system updates (unfortunately I cannot say which ones), `vmware.service` hangs during shutdown / reboot.

I discovered that if I manually stop that service (`systemctl stop vmware.service`) while `gdm.service` is still running (i.e. from Gnome terminal), the service is stopped quickly and shutdown then is as fast as expected.
I've googled around and found that also on Fedora 21 there is a similar problem and one user ended up switching to lightdm to fix that.
I don't want to switch to lightdm so I'm wondering if there is any way to tell systemd to stop `vmware.service` before stopping `gdm.service`.
Or if anyone has a workardound for that...

Answer (score 0):

Surely, there is a way. `systemd` supports specifying so-called "ordering dependencies" between pairs of units which make `systemd` follow a certain mutual ordering when these units happen to be activated/deactivated in a single transaction.

From [systemd.unit(5)](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Before=):

> Before=, After=
>
> A space-separated list of unit names. Configures ordering dependencies between units. If a unit foo.service contains a setting Before=bar.service and both units are being started, bar.service's start-up is delayed until foo.service is started up. <...> **Note that when two units with an ordering dependency between them are shut down, the inverse of the start-up order is applied.** i.e. if a unit is configured with After= on another unit, the former is stopped before the latter if both are shut down. <...>

So, you want `vmware.service` to be deactivated (stopped) before `gdm.service` is stopped. Per the above, can be achieved by adding a `After=gdm.service` ordering dependency to the `vmware.service` unit.

In order to avoid copying the whole unit to `/etc/systemd/system`, you may want to use the mechanism of [drop-ins](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Examples) (see "example 2"). You need to create a file named `/etc/systemd/system/vmware.service.d/<some name>.conf` with only the required directives and section headers:

```
[Unit]
After=gdm.service
```

After doing this, issue a `systemctl daemon-reload` command to make `systemd` re-read the units. On shutdown, the new dependency list should become effective.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Your answer is formally correct, however vmware daemon still hangs on shutdown... :(

Comment: Then it needs more investigation. I suppose the reason is that "stop before gdm" ≠ "stop before user sessions exit", and vmware actually needs the latter. However, I don't know whether this is achievable at all.

Comment: Yes I understand what you say... so I ended up adding TimeoutStopSec=1
to my vmware.service. I know it's not an elegant solution but it works.